# Display responsive header in single line using Bootstrap (Reactstrap)

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am making a react app with Reactstrap css framework and the `js` file looks,

**Example.Js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  Container,
  Button,
  Badge
} from "reactstrap";

const links = [
  { href: "#home", text: "Home" },
  { href: "#card", text: "Product" },
  { href: "#about", text: "About" },
  { href: "#cata", text: "Categories" },
  { href: "#test", text: "Blogs" },
  { href: "#test2", text: "News" },
  { href: "#busns", text: "Adds", className: "btnadd" },
  { href: "/login", text: "LOGIN" }
];

const createNavItem = ({ href, text, className }) => (
  <NavItem>
    <NavLink href={href} className={className}>
      {text}
    </NavLink>
  </NavItem>
);

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Navbar light expand="md" className="navbar-style">
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/candidbusiness/image/upload/v1455406304/dispute-bills-chicago.png" />
            </NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarBrand href="/">The Big brand title will be displayed here !</NavbarBrand>
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                {links.map(createNavItem)}
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem className="cart-wrapper">
                <Button className="cart-style" color="primary" size="sm">
                  Cart
                </Button>
                <Badge className="badge-style"> 10 </Badge>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here for normal view it is fine but while we view it in responsive view, the toggler in first row, the navbar logo was moved to next row then navbar title (little bigger in characters) in another row and finally cart button with badge in another row.

So the above one needs to be changed into a single line in responsive (Mobile view).

It should look like,

```
---------------------------------------------------------

toggle-button  brand-icon brand-title  cart-button-badge 

---------------------------------------------------------
```

The brand title can be displayed by break line like,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

toggle-button  brand-icon   The Big brand title        cart-button-badge 
                            will be displayed here !

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly help me to achieve the above mentioned result of making the header to display in a single line when viewed in responsive.

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-navbartoggler-example-mhvfmc

Even for normal bootstrap itself I am facing this issue,

**Pure Bootstrap Ref:** https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/NWPaQGB

The below given image is the reference that I already have in my old application which uses MUI css but now I need to replace the same with bootstrap and need to have exactly the same output as like given below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!The thing is you cant adjust all these div in a single row in a responsive view because of the devices width the possible best solution is btn+logo+cart in single row and under that the main heading, If you need i can show you this

Comment: No I am already having one old app where it was made like that in a single line using MUI css.. BUt now I need to do it using pure bootstrap..

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of that

Comment: @Awais, I have added screenshot for the same.. Please look into it..

Comment: @Awais, Can you help me in making like the screenshot mentioned above? It is ok it can be in pure css format and the solution provided below makes the toggler menu malfunctioning .. SO could you help me to male things ike the image provided?

Comment: Yes this is possible as you can see their is short view of your logo so the space adjust. ill provide you CSS and HTML in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution as per requirement of you question

> You can change the media query screen size as per req, Below query
>   cover tab and phone, Just pase the below code in your global styles

**CSS**

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
            .navbar-style > .navbar-brand {
        width: 55%;
        font-size: 13px;
        white-space: pre-line;
        text-align: center;
        padding-right: 26px;
    }
            .logo.navbar-brand {
                width: 50px;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            .logo img {
                width: 245px;
            }
            button.cart-style.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm {
                border-radius: 50%;
                padding: 8px;
                height: 42px;
                width: 42px;
            }
            li.cart-wrapper.nav-item {
                position: relative;
            }
            span.badge-style.badge.badge-secondary {
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 50%;
                font-size: 10px;
                height: 20px;
                width: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0;
                line-height: 19px;
                right: -4px;
                top:-4px;
                background: red;

            }
ul.ml-auto.cart.navbar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 15px;
}
}
```

Your Render **HTML**(Replace)

> Changes: (Just added the className `logo`)

```
        <Container>
          <Navbar light expand="md" className="navbar-style">
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
            <NavbarBrand className="logo" href="/">
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/candidbusiness/image/upload/v1455406304/dispute-bills-chicago.png" />
            </NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarBrand  href="/">The Big brand title will be displayed here !</NavbarBrand>
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                {links.map(createNavItem)}
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
            <Nav className="ml-auto cart" navbar>
              <NavItem className="cart-wrapper">
                <Button className="cart-style" color="primary" size="sm">
                  Cart
                </Button>
                <Badge className="badge-style"> 10 </Badge>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar>
        </Container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I have tried you solution here https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-navbartoggler-example-e79dis everything is fine.. But while toggling the cart button also getting toggled but it should not do .. It is separate from collapsible menu and it should be separate.

Comment: Sorry i didnt test that , Updated my code please check added calss `cart` in html and style this to stick to top

Answer (score 1):

NavBar component have inbuild css flex-wrap: wrap

```
  change wrap to nowrap: (overwrite css)

      <Navbar light expand="md" className="navbar-style" style={{ flexWrap:'nowrap' }}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. It is viewed in single line and that is ok.. But I am now getting horizontal scroll because the title is bigger, so I would like to make the title also should wrap within the space which I have mentioned in question already.. The responsive view should not have any horizontal scroll bar..

Comment: If you don't want horizontal scroll bar, use width as a percentage(write css like width: '20%'). But make sure it should be below or equal to the 100%. Like toggle button 20% + brand Icon 30% + title 30% + button badge 20%

Comment: I have edited my question please look at the added screenshot which is my expected result..

Comment: I just looked after making the change you mentioned, If I toggle the toggler in responsive then the menus are not visible which already visible in the example I have provided in question, https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-navbartoggler-example-mhvfmc

Comment: For toggle don't mention any width. Also you need to maintain two different UI for mobile and desktop.